# solicitação de exemplos - como incorporar React.Video em JavascriptXML?

Tags: react

Encontro-me de momento a desenvolver um projecto frontend/visualização de dados em que precise de incorporar o modulo de node.js `React.Video`, em `Javascript`, `XML`, ou `JSX`.

O projecto pode ser encontrado em: https://github.com/tiagomoraismorgado/estatisticasincendiosportugal

O código fonte da minha pagina é o seguinte

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var Cassette = require("react-cassette-player");
var ReactVideo = require("react.video");
var Header = require("../components/header.jsx");
var Footer = require("../components/footer.jsx");
var Jumbotron = require("../components/jumbotron.jsx");
var Router = require("react-router");
var Link = Router.Link;
var ImageTag = require("../components/imagetag.jsx");
var generateHelmet = require("../lib/helmet.jsx");
var SpeakersPromo = require("../components/speakers-promo.jsx");


var speakersInfo = require('../talks/2017');

var Home = React.createClass({
  pageMetaDescription: "Three days of building a truly global web together. Come with an idea, leave with a community.",
  render: function () {
    var self = this;
    return (
      <div className="home-page">
                    <Cassette src="http://localhost:9090/assets/audio/1.mp3"
                      preload="none"
                      cassetteColor="#FFFFF"
                      labelColor="#000"
                      tapeColor="#000"
                      controlsColor="#FFFF"
                      containerClass="quasi-wrap" />
                    );

        {generateHelmet(this.pageMetaDescription)}
        <Header logoImage="/assets/images/mozilla-festival_wordmark-interim_horizontal.jpg"/>
        <Jumbotron className="home-jumbotron" image="/assets/images/hero/home/banner-home_5.jpg"
                  image2x="/assets/images/hero/home/banner-home_5.jpg">
          <div className="content-wrapper">
            <h1>Plataforma de visualização de dados Incêndios Portugal 2017</h1>
            <p className="mb-0">Projecto de desenvolvimento frontend criado por Tiago Morais Morgado</p>
            <p className="mb-0">que tem em vista a criação de uma plataforma de visualização de dados com o propósito de fazer um ponto de situação em relação aos danos provocados por incêndios em Portugal em 2017</p>
          </div>
        </Jumbotron>
        <div className="news content wide">

        </div>
        <div className="white-background">
          <div className="centered content wide">
          <h1>Relatório de dados incêndios Portugal 2018</h1>
          <p>Abaixo poderá consultar os relatórios dos incêndios que assolaram o território nacional em 2017. Os relatórios contêm gráficos em formato 2d e 3d.</p>
          <a href="https://ti.to/mozilla/mozilla-festival-2018" className="btn btn-arrow"><span>Mais informação</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Home;
```

Tenho como exemplo o código do site do node package manager, que pode ser encontrado em:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react.video

a saber:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactVideo from 'react.video';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClickPlay = this.onClickPlay.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      muted: false,
      source: [
        {
          src: 'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4',
          type: 'video/mp4'
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  // play() method is called via refs. 
  onClickPlay () {
    this.refs.VideoComp.play();
  }

  render () {
    // a basic style object 
    const VideoStyle = {
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    };

    return (
      <ReactVideo
        ref={'VideoComp'}
        cls={'custom-video'} 
        height={500} width={'100%'}
        style={VideoStyle}
        muted={this.state.muted}
        src={'http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.mp4'}
        source={this.state.source}>
      </ReactVideo>

      <div>
        <div onClick={this.onClickPlay}>Play</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

contudo a sintaxe é radicalmente diferente e estou a  ter alguma dificuldade em integrar o código no meu projecto do meu site de visualização de dados dos danos causados pelos incêndios que assolaram Portugal em 2017, no meu repositório de github. se alguém puder ajudar-me no sentido de providenciar exemplos de como fazê-lo ficaria muy grato.

Comment: Onde tens/de onde vêm os URLs dos videos na app?

Comment: de um ficheiro local que está armazenado no próprio projecto na pasta /public/assets/video inclui agora URL do projecto para poderes ver melhor

Comment: também sou músico. estudei viola d'arco. andei dois anos em musicologia. estudei musica electronica produção musical na ESART (IPCB). fiz mestrado em sonologia no conservatório de Haia. tenho tentado ver se me viro mais para a parte da programação. tentei entrar no programa switch este ano. não entrei. tentarei novamente. contribuo incessantemente para opensource. tinha uma página que estava muito difusa e dispersa. tinha fork para ai de 500 repositórios. crei uma pagina nova para procurar foco. e fazer um portfolio para tentar fazer formação superior ou conseguir emprego na área